# Knockout jumping the gun when ajax is involved and acting as though events have fired when they haven't fired yet

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I am using `<details><summary>` elements as a quick "accordion" and fetching data when the user expands the element by clicking on the summary.  A fetch-data-only-on-demand scenario. It works when I populate the knockout observable array with test data "by hand" in my docReady initialization function. But if I bring ajax (`window.fetch`) into the picture, fetching the data in response to user action elsewhere on the page, knockout is jumping the gun and trying to execute a forEach binding on the array before it is populated, indeed, before it is even initialized.

In the markup below, the `details` element lacks an `open` attribute so it is closed by default. The element opening triggers the `toggle` event whose handler fetches data to populate the "edlns" array. knockout is acting as though the details.toggle event has fired, when it hasn't fired yet.

```
   <div id="TitlesContainer" data-bind="{visible:TitlesModel.showTitlesContainer, foreach: TitlesModel.Titles}">
        <details tabindex="-1" data-bind="event:{toggle: function(){TitlesModel.FetchPassages}}">
            <summary data-bind="text: name + ' (' + cat + ') [' + hits + ']'"></summary>
            <div class="hits" data-bind="foreach: edlns">
                <div class="passage-container">
                    <p class="edln" data-bind="text: '(' + edln + ')' "></p>
                    <p class="passage" data-bind="{html: text}"></p>
                </div>


            </div>
        </details>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I was not able to replicate your issue locally with stackoverflow snippets. but here is a snippet that others might be able to use as a starting point to help.

I suspect that it will be to do with knockout initialising variables with then cascade updates to other observables.  I have had issues like this, though not related to the events binding where I introduced an flag observable that would get set to true when loading and false when finished.  this allowed me to add a check for the flag in functions that were running to during the loading of the view/viewmodels.

```js
function Edln() {
  var self = this;
  self.edln = ko.observable();
  self.text = ko.observable();
}

function Title(data) {
  var self = this;
  let edln = new Edln();
  edln.edln(`Test ${data.hits}`);
  edln.text(`<strong>${data.name}<strong>`);
  
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name || '');
  self.cat = ko.observable(data.cat || '');
  self.hits = ko.observable(data.hits || 0);
  self.edlns = ko.observableArray([edln]);
  self.summary = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    return  `${self.name()} (${self.cat()}) [${self.hits()}]`
  });
}

function TitlesModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.showTitlesContainer = ko.observable(true);
  self.Titles = ko.observable([])
  self.FetchPassages = function(item) {
    console.log(`fetch passages ${item.name()}`);
  }
  let i = 0;
  let arr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var title = new Title({
      name: `Title Name ${i}`,
      cat: `Some cat ${i}`,
      hits: i
    });
    arr.push(title);
    self.Titles(arr);
  }

}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.TitlesModel = new TitlesModel();
}
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="TitlesContainer" data-bind="{visible:TitlesModel.showTitlesContainer, foreach: TitlesModel.Titles}">
  <details tabindex="-1" data-bind="event:{toggle: function(){$root.TitlesModel.FetchPassages($data);}}">
    <summary data-bind="text:summary"></summary>
    <div class="hits" data-bind="foreach: edlns">
      <div class="passage-container">
        <p class="edln" data-bind="text: '(' + edln() + ')' "></p>
        <p class="passage" data-bind="{html: text}"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </details>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks  for taking the time to put that together. I'll study it and apply it to my window.fetch situation and see if the problems I'm encountering are sorted out.